# Unknown JSON error on my PHP server

Tags: php, android, json

I'm working on an application that allows data transfer from Android to PHP server and I don't know why it doesn't support JSON?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
JSON.parse();
$decode = json_decode($_REQUEST['request']);
$json = $decode->name;
header('Content-type:application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: show some code..it will help to find out problem

Answer (score 0):

check your JSON at http://jsonlint.com 
If the JSON is valid than your php code may not be correct.

Show some code for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You can send Json data as string from android using following code :

```
BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Send data
        try {

            /* forming th java.net.URL object */
            URL url = new URL(this.url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();

            /* pass post data */
            byte[] outputBytes = jsonData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(outputBytes);
            os.close();

            /* Get Response and execute WebService request*/
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
            if (statusCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                ResponseData= convertStreamToString(inputStream);

            } else {

                ResponseData = null;
            }
```

and in php,you can get data by adding following code :

```
    $post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $post_body = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($post_body));
    $reqData[] = json_decode($post_body);

    $postData = $reqData[0];
    echo $postData->name;
```